# Can I safely enable TTimer from a non-UI thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi

I'm using Delphi XE7 on Windows 10.

I have been using the following code for a long time, and just read the documentation on `SetTimer()`.  To state it simply, I am setting timers from non-UI threads, but Microsoft's documentation says they should only be set on the UI thread.  Extensive tests show my code works fine, but I can't trust my system to behave the same as other systems, or the Microsoft documentation to be 100% accurate.  Can anyone verify whether this code is OK or not OK?

The Delphi code will not deadlock, it pretty much just calls `SetTimer()` (I am aware there is a race condition setting `TTimer.FEnabled`).

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) says:

> hWnd
>
> Type: HWND
>
> A handle to the window to be associated with the timer. This window must be owned by the calling thread.

What I'm trying to accomplish is worker threads doing stuff, and when appropriate, they notify the main thread that elements of the UI must be updated, and the main thread updates the UI.  I know how to use `TThread.Synchronize()`, but deadlocks can happen in certain cases.  I can use `PostMessage()` from my worker threads and handle the message in the UI thread.

Is there any other way in Delphi to notify and update the UI thread?

```pascal
unit FormTestSync;

interface
uses SysUtils, Classes, Forms, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Controls;

type
  TypeThreadTest = class(TThread)
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
      timer_update: TTimer;
      Label1: TLabel;
      procedure timer_updateTimer(Sender: TObject);
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    private
      m_thread: TypeThreadTest;
      m_value: integer;

    private
      procedure Notify(value: integer);
    public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TypeThreadTest.Execute;
begin
  while (not terminated) do begin
    //do work...
    form1.Notify(random(MaxInt));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer_update.enabled := false;
  timer_update.interval := 1;
  m_thread := TypeThreadTest.Create();
end;

procedure TForm1.Notify(value: integer);
begin
  //run on worker thread
  //Race conditions here, I left out the synchronization for simplicity
  m_value := value;
  timer_update.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.timer_updateTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer_update.Enabled := false;
  label1.Caption := IntToStr(m_value);
end;

end.
```

Comment: As for `any other way`, you can introduce a message handler method for a custom message on the form and then do a SendMessage to the main form handle using that message id from the background thread. This is how `Synchronize` used to work internally in older versions of Delphi.

Comment: Your code is basically just reinventing `PostMessage()` badly, with a minimum latency of 1 millisecond and unknown side effects. And if you "can't trust ...the Microsoft documentation to be 100% accurate" then why would you trust someone answering your question here more?

Comment: If someone says "It crashed on my system", that would validate the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: I expect that writing code to send and process messages will be more cumbersome in Delphi than setting a timer, and I have many frames + controls in my application that need to be updated.  I am hoping to find whether there is any other good method of doing this in Delphi that I have not known about.

Comment: I'm not aware of the MS docs for SetTimer saying that it has to operate in the UI thread. So far as I know you can create timers in other threads so long as the associated window is also created in that thread, and so long as you pump messages in your thread. However I also doubt that a UI timer is the way to solver your problem. Do you want to run a message loop in your worker thread? No, I didn't think so.

Comment: 'I expect that writing code to send and process messages will be more cumbersome in Delphi than setting a timer, and I have many frames + controls in my application that need to be updated' it's not that difficult.  PostMessage() can signal two arguments to a message-handler, one of which could be the control instance that you wish to update.  So, you only need one message-handler.  Shtap messin' abite with Synchronize, SendMessage, polled queues etc and just use PostMessage:)

Comment: ..unless the updates are so frequent that they exceed the UI rendering rate, in which case yes, use a TTimer to poll and update the UI at a human-readable rate.  Otherwise, just PostMessage your stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TTimer` is being constructed in the main UI thread, when the `TForm` streams in its DFM resource. The `TTimer`'s constructor creates an internal `HWND` for the timer to receive `WM_TIMER` messages with.  That `HWND`  is thus owned by the main UI thread.

`TForm.Notify()` is setting the timer's `Enabled` property to `true`, which will call `SetTimer()`.  `Notify()` is being called in the context of the worker thread, not the main UI thread.  This *SHOULD NOT* work, as stated in [`SetTimer()`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer).  Only the main UI thread should be able to start the timer running, since the main UI thread owns the timer's `HWND`.

`TTimer.UpdateTimer()`, which is called internally by the setters of the timer's `Enabled`, `Interval` and `OnTimer` properties, will raise an `EOutOfResources` exception if `SetTimer()` fails.  So, calling `form1.Notify()` in `TypeThreadTest.Execute()` *SHOULD NOT* work.  The only way `SetTimer()` would not be called in that situation is if either:

- `Interval` is 0
- `Enabled` is `false`
- `OnTimer` is unassigned

Otherwise, your worker thread *SHOULD* be crashing.

As you have noted, your worker thread can alternatively use `TThread.Synchronize()` (or `TThread.Queue()`), or `PostMessage()` (or `SendMessage()`), when it wants to notify the main UI thread to do something.  These are viable and preferred solutions.  Personally, I would opt for `TThread.Queue()`, eg:

```pascal
unit FormTestSync;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Forms, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Controls;

type
  TypeThreadTest = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    m_thread: TypeThreadTest;
  private
    procedure Notify(value: integer);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TypeThreadTest.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    //do work...
    Form1.Notify(random(MaxInt));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  m_thread := TypeThreadTest.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  m_thread.Terminate;
  m_thread.WaitFor;
  m_thread.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Notify(value: integer);
begin
  //runs on worker thread
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      //runs on main UI thread
      Label1.Caption := IntToStr(value);
    end
  );
end;

end.
```

If you want to use `TTimer` instead for this work, what you could do is simply enable the timer in the main UI thread and leave it enabled, and just synchronize access to the data that the timer accesses periodically.  That would be perfectly safe, eg:

```pascal
unit FormTestSync;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Forms, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Controls, SyncObjs;

type
  TypeThreadTest = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    timer_update: TTimer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure timer_updateTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    m_thread: TypeThreadTest;
    m_value: integer;
    m_updated: boolean;
    m_lock: TCriticalSection;
  private
    procedure UpdateValue(value: integer);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TypeThreadTest.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    //do work...
    Form1.UpdateValue(random(MaxInt));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  m_lock := TCriticalSection.Create;
  timer_update.Interval := 100;
  timer_update.Enabled := true;
  m_thread := TypeThreadTest.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  m_thread.Terminate;
  m_thread.WaitFor;
  m_thread.Free;
  m_lock.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateValue(value: integer);
begin
  //runs on worker thread
  m_lock.Enter;
  try
    m_value := value;
    m_updated := true;
  finally
    m_lock.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.timer_updateTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //runs on main UI thread
  if m_updated then
  begin
    m_lock.Enter;
    try
      Label1.Caption := IntToStr(m_value);
      m_updated := false;
    finally
      m_lock.Leave;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**UPDATE:**

I did a quick test. When `SetTimer()` is called with a non-NULL `HWND` that is owned by another thread, sure enough on Windows XP, 7 and 10 (I did not test Vista or 8), `SetTimer()` **succeeds**, and the `WM_TIMER`/`TimerProc` is called in the context of the thread that owns the `HWND`, not the thread that is calling `SetTimer()`.  **This is NOT documented behavior**, so do not rely on it!  [`SetTimer()`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) clearly says the `HWND` "*must be owned by the calling thread*", as you stated in your question.

In any case, `TTimer` is a VCL component, and the VCL is inherently not thread-safe in general.  Even though your `TTimer` code "works", it is not a good idea to access UI components outside of the main UI thread anyway, that is just bad code design.  Stick with an alternative solution that is known to be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks Remy.  I don't remember how I started using the code but it DOES work, for me...  As part of a code review I checked the Microsoft documentation and was surprised to find it shouldn't be working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of TThread.Queue, I was not aware of that.

Comment: @user hmmm. I did a test, and the result was surprising. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Thread safety is extremely difficult.  I inserted `AllocateHwnd()` to replace `self.handle` according to mghie's comment.

Here is how I am planning to implement the UI notification + update.  It's not any more complicated than the TTimer approach, and it doesn't have any thread safety issues that I know of.  Different messages can be defined for different items that need to be updated.

If update notifications could be sent very rapidly, a variation on this theme is necessary to reduce the number of `PostMessage` calls.  Also modifications are necessary if `value` cannot fit into `WParam`.

```
unit FormTestSync;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Forms, StdCtrls,
  Controls;

type
  TypeThreadTest = class(TThread)
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
  end;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
      Label1: TLabel;
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    private
      const
        WM_UPDATE = WM_USER + 1;
      procedure OnMessage_Update(var message: TMessage);
    private
      m_thread: TypeThreadTest;
      m_hwndAlwaysThere: HWND;

    private
      procedure Notify(value: integer);
    public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation
{$R *.dfm}


procedure TypeThreadTest.Execute;
begin
  while (not terminated) do begin
    //do work...
    form1.Notify(random(MaxInt));
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  m_hwndAlwaysThere := AllocateHWnd(self.OnMessage_Update);
  m_thread := TypeThreadTest.Create();
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  m_thread.Terminate;
  m_thread.WaitFor;
  m_thread.Free;
  DeallocateHWnd(m_hwndAlwaysThere);
end;

procedure TForm1.Notify(value: integer);
begin
  //run on worker thread
  PostMessage(m_hwndAlwaysThere, WM_UPDATE, value, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnMessage_Update(var message: TMessage);
begin
  //run on UI thread
  label1.Caption := IntToStr(message.WParam);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Yes, it does have thread safety issues. When your method in the form class accesses `Self.Handle` and that handle hasn't been (re-)created yet, your window would be created within the wrong thread context. There's a reason the VCL has `AllocateHWnd()`.